# google-map-api is not working with custom input component

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I am using **google-map-api** for address suggestion when user type in `input filed`.
Suggestions are working fine if I use `<input ref={inputRef} />`.
But suggestions are **not** working and not requesting any API when I use custom component.
**Custom component is given below :**

```
<TextInput
  ref={inputRef}
/>
```

#### `<TextInput />` component is given below:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { node, shape, string } from 'prop-types';
import { Text as InformedText } from 'informed';
import useFieldState from '@magento/peregrine/lib/hooks/hook-wrappers/useInformedFieldStateWrapper';

import { useStyle } from '@magento/venia-ui/lib/classify';
import { FieldIcons, Message } from '../Field';
import defaultClasses from './textInput.module.css';

const TextInput = props => {
    const {
        after,
        before,
        classes: propClasses,
        field,
        message,
        ...rest
    } = props;
    const fieldState = useFieldState(field);
    const classes = useStyle(defaultClasses, propClasses);
    const inputClass = fieldState.error ? classes.input_error : classes.input;

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <FieldIcons after={after} before={before}>
                <InformedText {...rest} className={inputClass} field={field} />
            </FieldIcons>
            <Message fieldState={fieldState}>{message}</Message>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default TextInput;
```

If you want to get details about **inputRef** used in this code. Please refer https://www.telerik.com/blogs/integrating-google-places-autocomplete-api-react-app

Comment: From what I know is that `ref` is a built in prop of an `input` tag/element. So it won't make that much sense if you try to use it in a **custom** one.